# How to create an external hyperlink to a modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

The company i work for uses a modal window for our request an appointment feature. I want to create a hyperlink that i can use on social media to direct traffic to this form. How can i easily create a hyperlink without adjusting the website code to go directly to the modal window

Answer (score 0):

Simply use button and use the `btn-link` class to make it as a hyperlink

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xd3Ro3TPQcG9oqA8fdWG?p=preview)**